# How to update entire column into another table using oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I have two tables called `t1(id,ref_id) and t2(ref_id,id)` I need to update t1 's ref_id column which is empty using data from t2 ref_id .here id t1.id and t2.id has same value let's consider.
 t1 has

```
ID  REF_ID
123  
123  
124  
124  
124  
125
```

t2 has

```
REF_ID  ID
2010    123
2011    123
2012    124
2013    125
2014    124
2015    124
```

and my output would be

```
123 2010
123 2011
124 2012
125 2013
124 2014
124 2015
```

can that be done by a single update statement?
i have tried this one

```
update test_01 t1 set t1.ref_id=(select * from(select t2.ref_id from test_02 t2 order by t2.id ));
```

but no result.

Comment: Is there any other values in t1 which does not exists in t2. If not then why don't you truncate t1 and load it with table t2's values

Comment: ya obviously we can,but i need to try this method yar...becoz in future i might struck like this right!?

Comment: how this t1 is emptied or rather say how do you populate the t1.id?

Comment: see those table are non key attributes...no primary key in this

Comment: @Thiyagu-First of we can do it using cursors. And even if it can be done in single query how will you decide which refid to set to which id. There is no primary key in both the tables.

Comment: @Abhishek kumar:ya i have better idea but don't know how to implement...see in first table id is already sorted so in second table first we'll sort the data by using id then we can  update by using row id!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
update t1
set ref_id = (select t22.ref_id
                from (select rowid ri,  id, ref_id, row_number() over (partition by id order by 1) rn 
                        from t1 ) t11 join
                     (select id, ref_id, row_number() over (partition by id order by 1) rn
                        from t2) t22 on t11.id = t22.id and t11.rn = t22.rn
             where t11.ri = t1.rowid);
```

[Here is a sqlfiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/87bad/15)

Since I used a window function (row_number) you might consider doing it with a merge:

```
merge into t1 d
using (
  select t22.ref_id, t11.ri
                from (select rowid ri,  id, ref_id, row_number() over (partition by id order by 1) rn 
                        from t1 ) t11 join
                     (select id, ref_id, row_number() over (partition by id order by 1) rn
                        from t2) t22 on t11.id = t22.id and t11.rn = t22.rn  
) s
on (d.rowid = s.ri)
when matched then update set d.ref_id = s.ref_id
```

[Here is another sqlfiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/87bad/14)